# How do I query a sequelize database and return a list that meets an arbitrary amount of user-entered criteria presented in a list with NODE.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

The user-entered criteria is of an arbitrary, user-defined length, and any element in the list returned must pass that criteria (eg. a certain column of every element must be equal to a certain list of numbers). Since we don't know the length of the list of criterion before-hand, we cannot do a big OR statement like so:

```
$or: [
{
  title: {
    $like: 'Boat%'
  }
},
{
  description: {
    $like: '%boat%'
  }
}
```

]
}

// title LIKE 'Boat%' OR description LIKE '%boat%' in http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/.

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to be careful with the wording of your question;  when you start listing requirements, you get very close to the line between asking for help and asking for someone to craft a solution for you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I added that because that's a problem i've been facing. I've since taken it off. My main question still stands, however, which is querying a db with an arbitrary number of parameters and returning a list.

Comment: Are the parameters to apply as OR, or AND? Or does the user specify that too?